# When redirecting from http to https in a shop site, which status code should I use?

Tags: redirects, 301-redirect, https, 302-redirect, 303-redirect

On a shop website, when "Pay now" is clicked we perform a header redirection to the same URL, just an SSL secured https version.

In such a common scenario, should we use a permanent (301), a temporary (302) or any other status code? Somehow, neither permanent nor temporary feels right (though I guess the latter will be more appropriate).

Comment: Huzzah - 3 conflicting answers (and counting?)...

Comment: Interesting. I thought there would be some kind of a standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For more information on response codes, see: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html (or http://urivalet.com/reason-phrases/ for a summary).

To answer your question, and to allay the issues with the `303` response (that some clients don't understand it), you would be safer to stick with a `302`.

Answer (score 4):

If you are always redirecting to the SSL site, then a `301` would fit … but you might as well just change the URL you link to instead of redirecting.

Comment: Can't do that, for various reasons the redirect must happen from code.

Answer (score 3):

A [`303 See Other`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_303) may be the most appropriate in this scenario.